# Batch scripting not setting variable to value

Tags: windows, batch-file

I typed this and it's not working at all

```
set ifpath=C:\Program Files\App

if exist %ifpath% SET ppath=C:\Program Files ELSE SET ppath=C:\Program Files(x86)

echo "%ppath%\App"
```

Simple but I spent hours trying to get the script to work. It keeps missing the ppath when echoing. If I remove the conditions and simply set ppath to a path, it shows.

The goal is to detect if Program Files(x86) exists or not and then install there if it exists otherwise just Program Files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 problems.

1) Your `%ifpath%` must be quoted because it contains spaces. Without quotes, the IF EXIST thinks the name stops a the first space.

2) The batch parser doesn't know when the value for your SET command ends. It is treating the ELSE clause as part of the value. That is easily solved with parentheses.

```
set "ifpath=C:\Program Files\App"
if exist "%ifpath%" (SET ppath=C:\Program Files) ELSE SET ppath=C:\Program Files(x86)
echo "%ppath%\App"
```

Let us suppose you reversed the test and started with the `(x86)` version. Simply adding parentheses wouldn't solve the problem because the parser would think the value ends at the 1st parenthesis in `(x86)`. That can be solved by escaping:

```
set "ifpath=C:\Program Files(x86)\App"
if exist "%ifpath%" (SET ppath=C:\Program Files(x86^)) ELSE SET ppath=C:\Program Files
echo "%ppath%\App"
```

Or a better way is to use quotes:

```
set "ifpath=C:\Program Files(x86)\App"
if exist "%ifpath%" (SET "ppath=C:\Program Files(x86)") ELSE SET "ppath=C:\Program Files"
echo "%ppath%\App"
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like this:

```
if exist "%ifpath%" ( call :PF ) else ( call :PFx86 )
:PF
set "ppath=c:\Program Files"
goto :EOF
:PFx86
set "ppath=c:\Program Files(x86)"
goto :EOF
```

Sometimes I do `call` statements like that when the nebulous scope of `if` and `for` confounds me.  I admit it's hackish and wasteful, but it's great for putting a band-aid on your life and moving on.  :)

Comment: @netrox - Not so fast. You still have a problem. Your IF statement is probably always returning FALSE. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14511321/1012053)

Comment: Still not correct. Create file "A B.TXT" and then run `if exist A B.TXT (echo exists) else echo not exists`. Result will be "not exists", unless file named "A" exists, then will get error saying "B.TXT" is not a command. Solution is to enclose the name in quotes.